# Python : how to count amount of letters of alphabet in string in parts

Tags: python

How to count the amount of letters in this string between the different parts? 
And the other way around: how to get the alphabetical string representation when the numbers are given?

Input: 'A-G H-O P Q-Z'

Output: (7, 8, 1, 10)

```
  q = list()

    for i in seq:
        if i is char:
            n = ord(i+1) - ord(i)
            q.append(n)
```

Comment: What is a "part"?

Comment: for example A-G and another is H-O and P and the last one is Q-Z

Comment: How are you receiving this input? What is this code you have posted?

Comment: So you're trying to count the chars in each word in `ABCDEFG HIJKLMNO P QRSTUVWXYZ`?

Comment: The code you posted is only vaguely related to your task. What is `char`? You don't define it anywhere in that code.

Comment: @davy the input is a string representation ('A-G H-O P Q-Z'). This code is first a first attempt but I am searching for one that works

Comment: `[ord(x[-1]) - ord(x[0]) + 1 for x in 'A-G H-O P Q-Z'.split()]`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski  How to solve the question the other way around?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```
input_string = 'A-G H-O P Q-Z'
input_string = input_string.split()

q = []
for dletter in input_string:
    if '-' in dletter:
        q.append(1 + ord(dletter[2]) - ord(dletter[0]))
    else:
        q.append(1)
```

Alternatively without the `if` statement:

```
input_string = 'A-G H-O P Q-Z'
input_string = input_string.split()

q = []
for dletter in input_string:
    q.append(1 + ord(dletter[-1]) - ord(dletter[0]))
```

But this is a very [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47269862/python-how-to-count-amount-of-letters-of-alphabet-in-string-in-parts/47269988#comment81490834_47269862)

Comment: I think your `ord(n[2]) - ord(n[0])` is going to be off by one

Comment: Ah I see, it was inclusive of.

Comment: You can get rid of the if-statements and just do `q.append(1 + ord(dletter[-1]) - ord(dletter[0]))`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Ye, I can also do your fab list comprehension :)

Comment: You also do not need to specify the split character as ' '. This way also other whitespace characters will be respected.

Comment: @MrZ like so `.split()` ?

Comment: yes. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split describes it in more detail

Comment: Note though that without the if statement, you are not actually checking if the input is according to specifications. 'ABC' would be the same as 'A-C'. If this is "the best" is I guess highly project specific ;).

Comment: @MrZ by that logic I should change my `[2]` to an `[-1]` to be more general

Comment: Well, as I mentioned it really depends on your project. the `[-1]` for example will not catch typos `A-SD`, but allows for arbitrary stuff (except whitespaces) between the first and last character. Your current answer is appropriate for the question I think and the rest, everybody has to decide for themselves.

Comment: List comprehension: `[1 + ord(ele[2]) - ord(ele[0]) if '-' in ele else 1 for ele in input_string.split()]`

Comment: @GiantsLove: how to solve the question the other way around?

Comment: That's a new question

Comment: @Lien can you make sure to accept the answer for your question, this answer should give you an idea of how to do it the other way around. This isn't a code writing service - so attempt to solve it the other way around before asking SO

Answer (score 0):

```
a = "A-G  N B-Z"
a = a.split()
b = []
for i in a:
    b.extend([i.split("-")])
print(b)
for lists in b:
    if len(lists) > 1:
        print(lists, ":", ord(lists[1]) - ord(lists[0]) + 1)
    else:
        print(lists, ":", 1)
```

> Output

```
[['A', 'G'], ['N'], ['B', 'Z']]
['A', 'G'] : 7
['N'] : 1
['B', 'Z'] : 25
```

## Using list comprehension

```
a = "A-G  N B-Z"

b = [i.split("-") for i in a.split()]

print(b)
for lists in b:
    if len(lists) > 1:
        print(lists, ":", ord(lists[1]) - ord(lists[0]) + 1)
    else:
        print(lists, ":", 1)
```

> Output

```
[['A', 'G'], ['N'], ['B', 'Z']]
['A', 'G'] : 7
['N'] : 1
['B', 'Z'] : 25
```